# Building SDL2 with audio component only

Tags: visual-studio, audio, visual-c++, sdl, sdl-2

Is it possible to build SDL2 with the audio component only?

With the latest release (2.0.14), I have tried unchecking the joystick, video, events in CMake, but still keeps looking for these components (undefined reference) when linking to the actual application.

If SDL2's CMake can make you opt out these components, it does not make sense that it will search it again and throw undefined reference.

Adding it back will make the lib and exe size the same as you would not opting these components out.

Comment: What exactly do you pass to CMake? Undefined references to what functions? This is weird, since SDL2 (at least with default build settings) is supposed to look for libraries at runtime.

Comment: I am using the CMake GUI, uncheck all components except related to audio and using a SDL2 static build btw so no runtime/DLL.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see any difference with that gist. The project that I am working already solves that SDL2 without the mixer. What I am looking for is a solution to include the audio component only and have the binaries reduced which those solutions does not specify. Anyway, I will also try and ask those authors if they have some ideas.

Comment: This gist shows how to play audio with SDL2 (without SDL_Mixer): https://gist.github.com/armornick/3447121

Comment: Thanks Andrea, you just reposted the same gist from the other day. Btw, already got a response from the SDL author that this is not possible at the moment I would presume, unless others still have better ideas/solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I just asked this question/problem directly to Ryan C. Gordon a.k.a. SDL's author and apparently this is not possible (at the moment):

> "In theory you can drop all these subsystems, but in practice no one does this so it doesn’t surprise me that it doesn’t work.
> There’s a lot of interconnected bits of code that we probably take for granted (for example: the audio subsystem uses the event subsystem to alert about device hotplugging, etc)."

https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/building-with-audio-component-only/31160/3